# Python: How to automate two python scripts from third python script using date as parameter?

Tags: python, automation

I have two python scripts as follows and both scripts uses date as input_date variable. I usually run first cost.py by writing input_date of choice and wait for the program to finish. Then I run sales.py script by writing 'input_date' same as cost.py. Both the programs must run one after another by using same date as parameter.

```
cost.py

import pandas as pd
input_date = '12-31-2019'
def somefunction()

sales.py

import pandas as pd
input_date = '12-31-2019'
def otherfunction()
```

Is there anyway from third program where I can control the dates and run both the programs one by one without opening above scripts separately. I mean if I can just pass date as parameter in third python script and the same date goes to 'input_date' variable in both cost.py and sales.py and run both scripts automatically. Please suggest. If not not clear I can rewrite the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean but this could be a possible solution. In cost.py add a main function that does what the script does:

```
def main():
    #stuff.........
    #stuff.........
    #stuff.........
    #cost.py script
```

Then at the top of your main script, type the following: `import cost` and wherever you want to run that script just call `cost.main()` Make sure the scripts are in the same directory. This is the same for sales.py.
You can also add parameters. I think this is what you want, if not just let me know, hope this helps!

Also, can you post the code for both sales.py and cost.py so I can show you more clearly what I mean?

Comment: Thanks for reply@Cheese Man. Which part in the post you didnt understand ? I have two .py files and I have to run one after another without changing date in the above scripts manually. Instead I want to control the dates from third program through which dates must assign to 'input_date' variable in above scripts and run both the cost.py and sales.py, one after another.

Comment: what about my 'input_date' date parameter. Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: You can just add the parameters to the function